# Badges are removed or missing from account profile

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

Of the seven badges I've earned with my time on the site I've noticed that the count is now dropped down to two.

Can anyone tell me the specific reason behind this?

Comment: I still see 7 badges.http://superuser.com/users/341822/stephen your meta account has 2

Comment: Thank You so much, i noticed it now :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking at your meta profile. Your main profile still shows 7 badges

Comment: You are absolutely right. I confirmed it, Thanks